# Finding the n farthest points from any man-made structure within a country

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, proximity, pbf

I am trying to find the farthest points from any man-made structure in Denmark.

I have acquired an OpenStreetMap data extract of Denmark from [this page](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/denmark.html), in PBF format.

How do I compute a number of points that are the farthest from any man-made structure, using this data and software like QGIS etc.? Eg. the 10 most remote locations within the boundaries of the country.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your data is in a projected coordinate system, i.e. not a crs with degrees as units.

1. Convert your line and point layers to polygons by buffering them
2. Clip each layer with a study area polygon
3. Merge the layers
4. Convert the output to raster with "A fixed value to burn"=1 and a "nodata value"=0
5. "Proximity raster distance" tool
   [image]